# "x not in" vs. "not x in"

Tags: python, operators

I've noticed that both of these work the same:

`if x not in list` and `if not x in list`.

Is there some sort of difference between the two in certain cases? Is there a reason for having both, or is it just because it's more natural for some people to write one or the other?

Which one am I more likely to see in other people's code?

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to close an older question as a duplicate of a newer one. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255410, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The two forms make identical bytecode, as you can clearly verify:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('if x not in d: pass', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (d)
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 JUMP_IF_FALSE            4 (to 16)
             12 POP_TOP             
             13 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 17)
        >>   16 POP_TOP             
        >>   17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(compile('if not x in d: pass', '', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (d)
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 JUMP_IF_FALSE            4 (to 16)
             12 POP_TOP             
             13 JUMP_FORWARD             1 (to 17)
        >>   16 POP_TOP             
        >>   17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

so obviously they're semantically identical.

As a matter of style, [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) does not mention the issue.

Personally, I strongly prefer the `if x not in y` form -- that makes it immediately clear that `not in` is a single operator, **and** "reads like English".  `if not x in y` may mislead some readers into thinking it means `if (not x) in y` (inverting the value of "x"), it reads a bit less like English, and it has absolutely no compensating advantages.

The `if x not in y` form also makes the code much more readable when you have multiple conditions. For example, consider the statement `if not x in y and x in m`. A casual reader might think it means `if not (x in y and x in m)`, but would get a surprise since the code actually executes as `if (not x in y) and (x in m)`. So by moving the `not` next to the `in` operator it belongs to, you therefore make it clear that the `not in` only applies to that particular condition, rather than all of them.

Therefore, `if x not in y and x in m` has multiple readability benefits and is easier to understand regardless of programming experience. Furthermore, `not in` is the official name of the "not in" bytecode operator (as seen in the disassembly above), regardless of how the user writes it, which further confirms  that `not in` is Python's preferred style.

Let's also consider a similar statement. The `is not` condition. If you attempt to write `if not x is True`, it becomes really obvious how silly and backwards that pattern is. Neither of them make any sense logically, but it becomes extra obvious in that `is not` example.

In short, `if X is not Y` and `if X not in Y` are the preferred ways of writing these kinds of Python statements.

Comment: PEP 8 mentions a similar preference: “Use `is not` operator rather than `not ... is`. While both expressions are functionally identical, the former is more readable and preferred.”

Comment: @WalterTross That's a really good point. `if not x is True` really brings out the silliness of the `if not x in y` anti-pattern. Neither of them make any sense logically, but it becomes extra obvious in your example. The `X is not Y` and `X not in Y` are the preferred ways of writing both statements.

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: a not in b)
1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
          3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b)
          6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
          9 RETURN_VALUE      

>>> dis.dis(lambda: not a in b)
1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
          3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b)
          6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
          9 RETURN_VALUE
```

when you do "not a in b" it will need be converted for (not in)

so, the right way is "a not in b".

Answer (score 4):

`not x in L` isn't explicitly disallowed because that would be silly. `x not in L` is explicitly allowed (though it compiles to the same bytecode) because it's more readable.

`x not in L` is what everyone uses, though.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `a not in b` it is using the `not in` operator, whereas `not a in b` uses the `in` operator and then negates the result. But the `not in` operator is defined to return the same as `not a in b` so they do exactly the same thing. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin):

> The operators `in` and `not in` test for collection membership. `x in s` evaluates to true if `x` is a member of the collection `s`, and false otherwise. `x not in s` returns the negation of `x in s`.

Similarly there is `a is not b` versus `not a is b`.

The extra syntax was added because it makes it easier for a human to read it naturally.

Comment: The strange part is when you use the `dis` module, it shows that they both compare using `not in` despite what the docs say...

Answer (score 0):

It just personal preference.  You could also compare `if x != 3` and `if not x == 3`.  There's no difference between the two expressions you've shown.

Comment: Those are not identical. `!=` calls `__ne__` and `==` calls `__eq__`. In perverse cases your examples may have different results

Comment: True enough.  I should have added, "perversion aside"!