# how to find unmatch list which are content of another list, from comparision of list of lists(python)

Tags: python, list

i have two lists:

```
mylist1=[['a','1'],['a',''],['a','1'],['a','3'],['b','2'],['c','2'],['c','3'],['c',''],['c','2']]
```

and

```
mylist2=[['a','1','lemon'],['a','2','coconut'],['a','3','chocolate'],['a','4','watermelon'],['b','1','mango'],['b','2','apple'],['b','3','tree'],['b','4','apple'],['c','1','water'],['c','2','fire'],['c','3','mountain']]
```

I want to find out those lists from "mylist2" whose zero and 1st position items are not in "mylist1",like;

```
result=[['a','2','coconut'],['a','4','watermelon'],['b','1','mango'],['b','3','tree'],['b','4','apple'],['c','1','water']]
```

Also in above result consider lists mylist1[1]=['a',''] and mylist1[7]=['c',''] (has null in their 1st position) and 1st position is not matched with any list from mylist2.

is there any solution???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
[x for x in mylist2 if x[:2] not in mylist1]
```

Comment: Use `foo not in bar` instead of `not foo in bar`. It's more readable.

Comment: @Avaris, ah, quite right. And of course there's a stackoverflow question on the issue too :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481554/if-loop-x-not-in-vs-not-x-in

Comment: this uses O(N*M) operations (N,M = length of each list). If N*M >10**6 you will start to see a big slow down in performance, in which case I would recommend you change "x[:2] not in mylist1" to "tuple(x[:2]) not in set(map(tuple,mylist1))"

Comment: @robert king: yes my lists are too big!!! their N*M is at-least four times bigger than 10**6.

Comment: Then  I suggest you use sets to speed up lookup times.

Answer (score 0):

Finding overlapping / non-overlapping sets is easy by switching the list objects into `set` objects and using one of their methods for comparing the sets.

To get there, you might need to chop off the "data" part (the label string - chocolate etc.).

There are many ways to approach this. This is one example:

```
>>> aa = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d'],[5,'e']]
>>> ak = dict(aa)
>>> ak
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd', 5: 'e'}
>>> ak.keys()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a = set(ak.keys())
>>> b = set([4,5,6,7,8])
>>> a.difference(b)
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> ra = list(a.difference(b))
>>> aa = [[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d'],[5,'e']]
>>> aa
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
```