# Does the position of the not keyword make a different here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a difference between these two lines in how they work??

```
if not i in lst
```

vs

```
if i not in lst
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If loop: "x not in" vs. "not x in"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481554/if-loop-x-not-in-vs-not-x-in)

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations): "*`x not in s` returns the negation of `x in s`*" So that basically says that `x not in s === not (x in s)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["x not in y" or "not x in y"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738388/x-not-in-y-or-not-x-in-y)